# How do I sum up time in Access 2007-2016 for worktime traking?

Tags: ms-access

I am having trouble with my DB to track working time. I can make entries in hh:mm. The point where I am struggling is this, I cant get a proper sum of all the hours in order to calculate if the employee has met his workload for each month. The only thing I get close enough to a sum is a total-field which shows everything below 23:59 perfectly but starts from  00:00 again as soon as the 24 hour mark has been passed.

The DB contains several Tables, one of them includes all the records with the according daily sum. And another one includes 12 records each for one month of the year. So it would look like this:

January    160:50
February   158:40
etc.

The total of each month is calculated using the date and daily sum of the employees records and the required workload is subtracted by the calculated month total. The result shows how many overtime/minus hours the employee has.

I also have trouble to enter the monthly required workload as hh:mm, as soon as I pass the 24 hour mark it forces me to convert the column to text.

I am getting quite desperate for I am stuck with this problem for a while now. I (belive) i checked every Google result regarding this issue but made no progress. I am an absolute novice in regards of Access and would appriciate if someone had the time to help me through this.

-Google
-Total field

Answer (score 0):

The sum field is probably working just fine. The problem here is that, for time fields, Access never displays over 24 hours, and instead moves it to days.

To display the number of hours elapsed as a total, you can use `DateDiff`:

```
DateDiff("h", 0, Sum(TimeField))
```

If you want to append the minutes to it, you can use `Format` for that:

```
DateDiff("h", 0, Sum(TimeField)) & ":" &  Format(Sum(TimeField), "nn")
```

Note that this does convert the field to a string. You can't have times larger than 24 hours as time fields, Access just doesn't support that, you either have to convert it to days + time as a fraction, or a string.

This assumes you're properly storing only time in your time field. If there are dates in there too, you can strip them out using `TimeField - Int(TimeField)`

Comment: Erik have you any spare time left for me? I could really use your help

Comment: I don't do personalized guidance, but if you have a question, feel free to ask and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Okay much appriciated, so I have a table where I store all records of every employee. The column where I enter the coming/going times and the daily sum are all in Time, 24h format. The monthly sum is a result of a query and I don't really don't know how to apply your solution to my DB.

Comment: Well... you can just use it as an expression in a totals query, like the one calculating your monthly sum. Just swap that sum with this expression, fill in the fields, and it should work.

Comment: So correct me if I am wrong; I go to the edit view of the query which shows the monthly sum and insert into a blank field: Monthly Sum: DateDiff("h", 0, Sum(TimeField)) & ":" &  Format(Sum(TimeField), "nn")

Comment: Doesn't work though

Comment: I neither have a clue what you did exactly, nor what didn't work. You need to use a totals query, and use it as an expression.

Comment: Hmm so what I did was I opened a query already existing and went to the edit view. There's already a field named "EmployeeID" and the second one is blank. There, in the "Field" box I insert "Monthly Sum: Daily Sum" and use the function Sum. It does a good job until it passes 23:59. That's all I got